# Как получить соседние элементы list'a и изменить их?

Tags: java, list

Как получить, соседние элементы списка, чтобы их потом заменить.

Например вот список:

```
[-1, 0, -1, 0, 1, -1]
```

Нужно получить

```
[-1, 1, -1, 0, 2, -1]
```

Т.е. относительно всех элементов `-1` слева от них, добавить всем элементам `1`

Comment: Ответ нашел, list.set(list.lastIndexOf(-1)-1, 1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если сделать как в комментарии, вы обработаете только последнее вхождение -1 в исходный лист и замените предыдущий элемент на 1
Чтобы обработать каждый элемент == -1 нужно перебрать список циклом и не присваивать, а добавлять единицу к предыдущему элементу:

```
//формируем массив
Integer[] arr = {-1, 0, -1, 0, 1, -1};
ArrayList<Integer> list =  new ArrayList<>();
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));

//проходимся циклом с проверкой
for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++)
    if (list.get(i) == -1) {
        list.set(i - 1, list.get(i - 1) + 1);
    }

//смотрим результат
System.out.println(list);
```

Проверять список нужно начиная со второго элемента, т.к. попытка добавить единичку к элементу левее первого вызовет исключение.

Comment: все ок пасиб, бро